# Pouchdb timeout error

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm have a bug using pouchdb. I replicate my pouchdb to my local couchdb server, and this works fine for the first few replications. However, it then starts to have a lot of timeout errors and stops being able to replicate to the remote. This error doesn't happen when I go in incognito mode in chrome, and everything works fine. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/issues/29